# C# best practice: Editable state is a reference so still connected

Tags: c#, class, reference, field

I have a CameraComponent class. It contains a class called CameraState. A simplified example:

```
public class CameraState
{
    public float zoom = 1f;
    // a number of other fields, some value types, some reference types...
}

public class CameraGameComponent
{
    private CameraState currentCameraState = new CameraState();

    public CameraState CurrentCameraState
    {
        get { return currentCameraState; }
        set { currentCameraState = value; }
    }
    //...
```

The idea is that another class can create a new CameraState, set it up, and then set CurrentCameraState to make the camera use that new state. That works fine.

Alternatively that other class can get the CurrentCameraState, store it or change it as desired (in which time other parts of the code may change CurrentCameraState), and then set the CurrentCameraState to make the camera use that stored state.

The problem is that when the other class reads the CurrentCameraState and then changes its version of the state, the state in the camera is also changed. For example:

```
// in another class
// Camera.CurrentCameraState.zoom is currently 1f
CameraState state = Camera.CurrentCameraState;
state.zoom = 20f;    // line 1
CameraState testState = Camera.CurrentCameraState;
float testzoom = testState.zoom;    // line 2
// at this point testzoom is 20f, not 1f
```

I would like the changing of zoom in line 1 not to affect the zoom value in the Camera.CurrentCameraState, so that at line 2 testzoom has a value of 1f.

Similarly, if

```
// in another class, class 1
// Camera.CurrentCameraState.zoom is currently 1f
CameraState state = Camera.CurrentCameraState;
```

[...]

```
// elsewhere, in yet another class, class 2
Camera.CurrentCameraState.zoom = 20f;
```

[...]

```
// at a later point in class 1
float testzoom = state.zoom;    // line 3
// at this point testzoom is 20f, not 1f
```

I want testzoom at line 3 to be what it was when it was stored, ie 1f.

I know why this happens (CurrentCameraState returns a reference), and I can think of a number of ways to stop it happening (return a new deep copy of the CameraState class, use a struct, get the Camera class to handle storing and restoring of states, etc) but my question is:

What is the best practice way to achieve this for this sort of usage? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want `CameraState` to be a value type (struct). If you want this behavior for all instances of `CameraState`, and not just those within a `CameraGameComponent`, then just use a struct.

If you need `CameraState` within `CameraGameComponent` to behave differently from all other instances of `CameraState`, then you need to change the behavior of the `CurrentCameraState` property. The getter would have to return a copy of the `CameraState`, and the setter would have to set the properties:

```
public class CameraGameComponent
{
    private CameraState currentCameraState = new CameraState();

    public CameraState CurrentCameraState
    {
        get {
            var cs =  new CameraState{};
            cs.zoom = currentCameraState.zoom;
            return cs;
        }
        set {
            currentCameraState.zoom = value.zoom;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So best practice is: If you want this behavior for all instances, use a struct. If you need CameraState within CameraGameComponent to behave differently from all other instances of CameraState then use a deep copy. Have I got that right?

Comment: Yes. A deep copy or the equivalent. And I don't go as far as to call that "best practice". It's just pretty much obvious.

Comment: I suppose when I say 'Best Practice' I partially mean not missing something else even more obvious... :) Thanks, marked as answer.